# time triggert function, cell error handling

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The time triggered function I'm calling got a fixed range. It validates this range and sends an email if necessary. This works so far but sometimes I got just errors. I assume the content of the range is not loaded, but I'm not sure. With your help, I want to improve the error message I got or figure out how to solve that problem.

**sendMailToCheckedMembers** is the time triggert function

**getMembersFromRange** gets the values of the cells, returned as a map

```
function sendMailToCheckedMembers(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(MAIN_PAGE);
  var rangeToCheck = sheet.getRange("L5:P28");
  var map = getMembersFromRange(rangeToCheck);

  //check for errors
  for (var ele in map) {
    if(isErrorOrLoading(ele)){
      sendError(createStringFromMap(map));
      return;
    }
  }    
  //do validation stuff 
  //send validation mail
}

function getMembersFromRange(range){
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var map = {};
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      var currentCell = range.getCell(i,j).getValue();
      var entryArray = currentCell.split(" ");
      for(var k=0;k<entryArray.length;k++){
        map[entryArray[k]] = entryArray[k];
      }
    }
  }
  return map;
}
```

this line `var currentCell = range.getCell(i,j).getValue();` contains sometimes the String `#ERROR!` but it seams like no further information.

I tried to work with sleep(time) to just wait a few seconds after I found errors and then just try it again, but this does not help at all. I don't know what the error is about.

I'm searching for something like `range.getCell(i,j).getErrorText()` or a way to just wait for the sheet to finish loading the cell's content.

Like I sad above the expected validation email is send 4 out of 7 days and the other 3 days I just get the error mail.

I hope you have some ideas that a can check.
thanks!

**Edit:**
The content of the cells are filled with the following custom script:

```
function conCatDates(rangeAsString,range){
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  var rangeArr = rangeAsString.split(";");
  var returnValue =[];
  for(var i=0;i<rangeArr.length;i++){
    var splited = rangeArr[i].split("!");
    var sheetname = splited[0];
    if(args[i] != ""){
      returnValue.push(sheetname);
    }
  }

  if(returnValue.length==0){
    return "";
  }
  return returnValue.sort().join(" ");
}
```

**conCatDates** example input conCatDates("Sheetname1!G13;Sheetname2!G13";Sheetname1!G13;Sheetname2!G13), goal of that function is, to get the sheetname of all not empty cells

Comment: I would recommend you redo your `getMembersFromRange(range)` function. Instead of 2 `for` loops, you should just get all the data at once and and loop throgh the array with `valueArray[row][column]. The `#ERROR!` seems like it's due to a formula not being calculated. Are the values in the cells set by formulae? What is the formula that sets the data?

Comment: thanks for correcting spelling and grammatic.
deleting the 2 loops to iterate over an 2 dimension array that takes 2 loops? i dont get it whats the point of that improvement?

Comment: yes the formular is filled by a custom script, and yes some of the cells are calculated while the triggered function is running and others are not.

Comment: by 2 loops (I actually missed one) I mean that you do a `for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++)`  and `for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++)` to get the values from the spreadsheet, which is not necessary and is better done with a single `.getValues()`

Comment: i still don't understand that, are you not seeing that im working with every value? if i would work with getValues nothing would change except that just one line would be outside of the loop. But why? Thats maybe code style but no improvement at all. if there would be an for each loop .... than i would say yes! but as far as i can tell, there is no.

Comment: if you say thats bad codestyle, than i have to ask why?

Comment: As per Googles own recommendations doing constant read or write commands is slow and you should ideally read all the data at once and then output it back again https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations

Comment: ok, thats a good point, i will change it

Comment: i also replaced conCatDates with a function like this `=JOIN("";IF(Sheetname1!G17 <> "";"Sheetname1 ";"");IF(Sheetname2!G17 <> "";"Sheetname2 ";"");...)`
this is much faster than an custom function doing the same, maybe that solve the loading problem